# I want to generate java code from wsdl file

Tags: java, soap, wsdl, maven-plugin

I have the .wsdl file with me

I need to generate the below files from it.
-Service interface
-Service implementation
-Data binding classes
-Client and server stub classes

I used below plugin

```
<dependency>
  <groupId> jakarta.xml.ws </groupId>
  <artifactId> jakarta.xml.ws-api </artifactId>
  <version> 4.0.1 </version>
</dependency>

<plugin>
  <groupId> com.sun.xml.ws </groupId>
  <artifactId> jaxws-maven-plugin </artifactId>
  <version> 4.0.1 </version>
</plugin>
```

And configured following below example

```
<configuration>
  <wsdlDirectory> src/main/resources </wsdlDirectory>
  <wsdlFiles>
    <wsdlFile> hexingws.wsdl </wsdlFile>
  </wsdlFiles>
  <packageName> com.example.myproject </packageName>
  <sourceDestDir> src/main/java </sourceDestDir>
</configuration>
```

I run

```
mvn jaxws:wsimport
```

It generates,
-Service interface
-Service implementation

but not generating other 2 files,
-Data binding classes
-Client and server stub classes

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to check if below snippet works?

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>com.sun.xml.ws</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxws-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>4.0.1</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <goals>
                <goal>wsimport</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <wsdlDirectory>src/main/resources</wsdlDirectory>
                <wsdlFiles>
                    <wsdlFile>hexingws.wsdl</wsdlFile>
                </wsdlFiles>
                <packageName>com.example.myproject</packageName>
                <sourceDestDir>src/main/java</sourceDestDir>
                <!-- Include binding files for data binding classes -->
                <bindingFiles>
                    <bindingFile>src/main/resources/your-binding-file.xml</bindingFile>
                </bindingFiles>
                <!-- Generate client and server stubs -->
                <genClient>true</genClient>
                <genServer>true</genServer>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <dependencies>
        <!-- Include the required dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.xml.ws</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxws-rt</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.5</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</plugin>
```

Make sure to replace your-binding-file.xml with the actual path to your binding file if you have one. Also, ensure that the required dependencies, such as jaxws-rt, are included in your project.

Comment: I tried this method still some issues are there.    1) I don't have a separate binding file    2) place of the <dependency> is invalid  3) after running the `mvn jaxws:wsimport` it say that `No WSDLs are found to process, Specify atleast one of the following parameters: wsdlFiles, wsdlDirectory or wsdlUrls.`
@Techie_Taks